# Form for deep association with CakePHP, almost working

Tags: forms, cakephp, model, associations

I'm writing my first Cake app and trying to set up my first deep association. It's very nearly working but I have a couple of small issues.

The first part of my app is a customer database. A customer has many addresses, and an address has many contacts. The data structure returned contains duplicated data from the address model.

```
Here's the 3 models:

class Customer extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = 'CustomerAddress';
}

class CustomerAddress extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = 'Customer';
    public $hasMany = 'CustomerContact';
}

class CustomerContact extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = 'CustomerAddress';
}
```

In my customer controller, I want to get associated addresses and their contacts. I can do this by setting recursion on the find command:

```
CustomerController.php 

public function find( $id = NULL) {
    $this->set('customers', $this->Customer->find('all', array( 'recursive' => 2)));
}
```

And this works brilliantly, with one caveat. The data structure returned looks like this:

```
array(
    'Customer' => array(
        'id' => '46',
        ....
    ),
    'CustomerAddress' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '35',
            'customer_id' => '46',
            .....

            'Customer' => array(
                'id' => '46',
                .....
            ),
            'CustomerContact' => array(
                (int) 0 => array(
                    'id' => '29',
                    'customer_address_id' => '35',
                    .....
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

At a glance, this looks fine, and for all intents and purposes works as the data is formatted how you'd expect. But, CustomerAddress also contains a Customer object, which is a duplicate of the top level Customer object. I assume this is because recursion is working with the belongsTo on the address model.

I've tried setting the recursion to 1, but then I only get the address not the contact. I've tried setting the recursion in the address model, but that doesn't seem to effect the find at the Customer level.

It's not a huge issue, just worried about future performance issues and unnecessary calls to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the reasons why it is discouraged to use the recursive setting.  Most turn off recursion (set it to -1) then use the Containable behavior to get associated models instead.  Make sure in AppModel, there is the line

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

Then, to get your data:

```
$this->Customer->find('all', array('contain' => array('CustomerAddress' => array('CustomerContact'))));
```

Comment: Cheers! I was looking at the Containable things but the Cookbook seems to be pushing them to limit what fields were returned. That worked great. Hopefully you can help with my next question too :)